# MonoTouch - how do I create a List with all the CGColor types efficiently

Tags: list, loops, xamarin.ios, addition, cgcolor

I am looking at an efficient way of creating a list of `CGColors` using `MonoTouch`.

This is what I have so far in a method:

```
List<CGColor> colourList = new List<CGColor>();
colourList.Add(UIColor.Blue.CGColor);
colourList.Add(UIColor.Brown.CGColor);
colourList.Add(UIColor.Cyan.CGColor);
```

It is easy for me to now randomly select one of those colors from the list, but I am looking for an efficient way of adding all the different options of `CGColor` to this List without needing to use `colourList.Add()` each time.

How can I run through each possible option (Blue, Orange, Green, Purple etc...) in a loop to add these into my List?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *efficient*. If you want this to be **fast** the continue using `Add` and built your own list.

You can drop some source code using a C# 3 feature, e.g.

```
List<CGColor> colourList = new List<CGColor> () {
    UIColor.Blue.CGColor,
    UIColor.Brown.CGColor,
    UIColor.Cyan.CGColor, ...
};
```

That looks better (IMHO) and it will be as fast to execute, since it will be identical once compiled to IL.

You can also use `System.Reflection` to find all static properties of `UIColor` (returning a `CGColor`) and add them to a list. That has the advantages that any new color added in future version of iOS will be added without changing your source code. However execution (to create the list) will be a bit slower. Also the managed linker might remove some the the colours when enabled (because they won't be seen as required by the application).

Finally if you want random colours then you could keep only the RGBA values and recreate a `CGColor` based on them. Take would take a smaller amount of memory and let you use a predefined array of RGBA values.

Comment: Thanks poupou, I should have clarified by efficient, I guess I meant neater way of writing the code and fast if possible. For now I will simply go with your way of simplifying the source code, and I have briefly looked into Reflection too - I was able to pull a list of all the UIColor static properties using that, so I may use that in future - it should be more than fast enough for my application :) - I had also thought about using random RGBA values - should be simple enough to use Integers between 0 and 255 to get that one going - maybe another method!